# Can wifi access be given to specific applications?

Tags: wifi, android-wifi

Which is the best appplication way to give access to free wifi to particular applications only (say whataspp)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible through a (logical)firewall between the wifi network and the gateway.
Whatsappp-packets can be detected by tcp port number and destination ip. 
there are some good wifi/gateway/firewall combi-devices, e.g all openWRT and routerOS devices